# Selenium: Get variable data from <script type> tag in Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

So I am trying my hand on selenium to scrape data from a website, as still new to selenium and web scraping I am stuck. I want to scrape some data which is present under `<script type>` tag, the tag looks like this:

```
...
...

<script type="text/javascript">
  var myData_1 = {"name" : ..... };
  var myData_2 = {......};
  var myData_id = 4565843;
  var myData_mapping = {.....};
</script>

...
...
```

So I need to scrape data present in this script tag i.e. all var data values. Till now I have coded down only this much:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/home/slothfulwave612/chromedriver_linux64/chromedriver')

driver.get('https://www.example.com') ## not the actual site

html = driver.page_source

print(html)

driver.close()
```

This is just printing the source code for the website, what should I add here so that I can scrape the data from `<script type` tag. Can somebody help?

Comment: Try `re.search('<script>(.*)</script>', html)`

Comment: Its returning `None`, but this worked for me `content = driver.execute_script("return myData_1;")`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the method `.find_element_by_xpath()` ([docs](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html))

```
script_label = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//script[@type = 'text/javascript']")
```

And then you can scrape the inner elements.

Comment: On printing script_label I am getting the following result: `<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="bdf16c59641dc3dddb89ba463e756536", element="0.5478719429608367-1")>`   How can I get the data

Comment: `script_label.text` is printing nothing.

Comment: `content = driver.execute_script("return myData_1;")` I found this and it worked, btw thanks

Comment: `script_label.get_attribute("innerHTML").text`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to print all the content of script tag use **innerHTML** attribute to print.

```
ele = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//script[@type = 'text/javascript']")
print(ele.get_attribute("innerHTML"))
```

**Output:**

var myData_1 = {"name" : ..... };

var myData_2 = {......};

var myData_id = 4565843;

var myData_mapping = {.....};